# how to show in a plot only the values that match with a condition? in python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, conditional-statements

I have this dataset:
[image]

And I want to show in the plot only the temperature that has its location_id = 1.

I tried this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = df['local_time'].where(df['location_id'] == 1)
y = df['temperature']

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Local time')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')
plt.title('Weather in London')
plt.show()
```

And I get this error: `TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float`

Could you please help me ?

Comment: `df2 = df[ df['location_id'] == 1 ]`, then `x = df2[ 'local_time']` and  `y = df2['local_time'']`

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```py
df.set_index('local_time', inplace=True)
df.loc[df.location_id==1].plot()
```